# python TypeError: expected string or buffer when parsing JSON from a file

Tags: typeerror

I realize this problem has been answered for other folks but none of the threads are helping me solve it. I'm trying to parse a JSON structure and add all values in the sent_file when the keys match with the tweet_file. The error I'm getting

```
import sys
import json





def main():
sent_file = open(sys.argv[1])
tweet_file = open(sys.argv[2])
scores = {}
#tweet = {}
#tweet_text = {}
#hw()
#lines(sent_file)
#lines(tweet_file)    
for line in sent_file:
    term,score = line.split("\t")
    scores[term] = int(score) 
#print scores.items()
for tweets in tweet_file:
    current_sent_value = 0
    tweet = {}  #this is a dict 
    #print type(tweets) str
    tweet = json.loads(tweets)#[0]  #this assignment changes tweet to a list. Why?

    if 'text' in tweet:
        tweet_text = {}
        unicode_string = tweet['text']
        encoded_string = unicode_string.encode('utf-8')
        tweet_text = encoded_string.split() 
        for key in tweet_text:
            for key in scores:                    
                    #print type(tweet_text) -- list
                    #print type(scores)   --dict
                    if tweet_text.get(key) == scores.get(key):  # get() does not work on a list. tweet_text is a list.
                        current_sent_value += scores(value)


    print current_sent_value
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()

The error is here \assignment1\tweet_sentiment2.py", line 42, in main
    if tweet_text.get(key) == scores.get(key):  # get() does not work on a list. tweet_text is a list.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: What does `tweets` look like if you print it out prior to json.loads()?

Comment: This is one of my challenges, when I print it goes by so fast I can't see it. When I scroll up to look at it I'm not familiar enough with it to discern what it is. It is a str

Comment: temporarily comment out all the other print statements, and make a test file with only a few lines.

Comment: the json.load turns it into a list, which is strange because my if 'text' inevaluation is true. I'm new and thought the if only worked to find keys in dicts

Comment: Can you add the actual output and updated code to your question?

Comment: So it looks like I am ending up with a list which I can't use the get() with.

Comment: So what's the question at this point?

Comment: I figured this out. It ends up I did not have to use dict and just compared the list. Your questions and help inspired me. Thank you